# Multiple optional parameters for report

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

My report has 2 required parameters (`Source; Location` and 2 optional ones `Access Type; Access Complication`) I've tested the query and can prove that works correctly. The report also works if I populate every param.

Without a complication param, all complications should return, but no patients. If only access type is chosen, it should get a list of patients with all complications assigned to the chosen access types. But I get *no* records if either of the parameters is left out.

I tried this `hasvalue` formula in the select expert, to no avail

```
(not hasValue({?AccessType}) OR {Command.AccessType} = {?AccessType})
 and
(not hasValue({?AccessComplication) OR {Command.AccessComplication} <= {?AccessComplication})
```

If I set a new formula for Access Type in the select expert, then for Access Complication with the above `hasvalue` formula, then whichever one I do second overwrites the first. They don't seem to be able to exist alongside each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used in a formula, optional parameters become mandatory parameters. End of story.

To achieve something similar, send your param as `all` or `*` (which means all records in SQL). Before selecting all the data, check your "optional" parameter values, and if they have `all` or `*` write a selection formula without including those parameters.

Pseudo code should look like this for 2 mandatory and 2 optional params:

```
if param3 = "all" or param4 = "all"
    if param3 = "all" and param4 = "all" select data only with param1 and param 2
    else
        if param3 = "all" select data without param3
        if param4 = "all" select data without param4
else select data with all params
```

Comment: Thanks KuKeC -  but given the complexity of the report i think it is easier to make all params mandatory and the users can just select all values if thats what is desired.

Comment: That would be the best outcome, so you don't have to look for all parameters values, just select them always by all 4. Hope it helped you

Comment: It did - Thanks again.